# Is it possible to upload images on overdrive using paperclip in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

For image storage I want to use overdrive. But can't find any way to upload in ruby on rails using paperclip

Is it possible ? If yes then how can we do that

Comment: Image storage? OverDrive seems to solely provide formats for audio books, videos, and ebooks. So, no. This quote literally comes from their FAQs "Pictures ... take up a lot of space on your device. You may want to consider deleting some, or transferring them to a computer, storage device, or cloud storage service." They clearly don't even recommend their own service for image uploads. I recommend you find a different API. Plus PaperClip recommends ActiveStorage!

Comment: @VeridianDynamics can we store audios there trough paperclip?

Comment: Yes I believe so, but the API docs were sparse on POST requests. I'm sure it can be done.